# Can't compare Jquery ajax object in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically I'm using jquery's ajax call to get an html page.  On success, a data object is returned.  I want to compare this data object to a string to determine what I need to do with it.  This works fine in Firefox and Chrome but does not work in IE.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'html',
  cache: false,
  success: function (data){ 
    if(data.endsWith('someTestString')) {
       //Do something
       console.log('hi');
    } else {
       //Do some other Thing
        console.log('hi2');
    }
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('there was an error');
  }
});
```

In IE I get the following error on this line if(data.endsWith('someTestString')) {

> Object doesn't support property or method 'startsWith'

I've tried using a couple ways to cast data to a string, so far nothing has worked.  So far I have tried:

data.toString()

string var = '' + data + '';  //Then compare to a string, still get an error

Here is the jsfiddle for this:
https://jsfiddle.net/qcy02eae/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE does not support the methods `.startsWith()` or `.endsWith()` on a string object.  Those functions are simple to code yourself or use a polyfill if not present.

For example, here's the polyfill for `.startsWith()` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
    position = position || 0;
    return this.indexOf(searchString, position) === position;
  };
}
```

And, similarly for `.endsWith()`:

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(searchString, position) {
      var subjectString = this.toString();
      if (position === undefined || position > subjectString.length) {
        position = subjectString.length;
      }
      position -= searchString.length;
      var lastIndex = subjectString.indexOf(searchString, position);
      return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
  };
}
```

You just add this code to one of your Javascript pages (before any code tries to use these methods) and if they are not already present on the built-in String prototype object, then these two blocks of code will add them so they can be used normally.  This is known as a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill).

---

FYI, in your jsFiddle, I see `data` with a value like this:

```
'{ "args": { "_": "1441149290759" }, "headers": { "Accept": "text/html, */*; q=0.01", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch", "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,pl;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4", "Cache-Control": "max-age=0", "Dnt": "1", "Host": "httpbin.org", "Origin": "https://fiddle.jshell.net", "Referer": "https://fiddle.jshell.net/qcy02eae/show/", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36" }, "origin": "67.180.86.230", "url": "https://httpbin.org/get?_=1441149290759" } '
```

Which looks like a JSON string.   Perhaps you should be parsing it with `JSON.parse()` and then you can examine the resulting Javascript object more directly than looking at it with string matching functions.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked great.  For the fiddle, I just needed a public place to use the ajax get request, I'm actually going to be getting html back.